# REST Api: how to pass the JSONresponse to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, rest

I just set up my first web service (REST Api) and it works correctly (checked with postman plugin on Chrome). I have three arguments that are in the JSONresponse:

```
{ "a": 1, 
"b": 5,
"c": 2
}
```

But now I want to pass these three arguments to javascript-code to use them there (for example printing them), but because I'm totally new to this, I have no idea how to do this.

I tried something like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "SomethingLike:/api/v1.0/name"

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
myFunction(jsonResponse)
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(data) {
console.log(data)
}
```

But when I run it with Sublime Text I get this error:

> Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: "Is this somewhat okay?" — Do you have some reason to think it isn't? Are you just looking for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I don't know how to test this code and if I run it right now I get: Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: How are you testing it currently to get a result like that? What JavaScript engine are you using? Where is it running?

Comment: I'm running JavaScript in sublime and I run the web service in python also in sublime

Comment: Is Sublime your target platform? Or is your actual intended target platform going to be JavaScript embedded in a webpage and run from a browser?

Comment: target platform is JavaScript embedded in a webpage

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: XMLHttpRequest
>
> I'm running JavaScript in sublime
>
> target platform is JavaScript embedded in a webpage

XMLHttpRequest is not native JavaScript, but is a standard object made available to the JS environment by web browsers.

I'm not entirely sure how you are getting Sublime to execute the JS, but it probably involves using Node.js which doesn't provide XMLHttpRequest.

If you want to develop JS that is intended to run in a webpage, then your first port of call should be to create a webpage and embed the JS in it, then load that page in a web browser. (Make sure you open the Developer Tools and look at the Console to see any error messages).

---

It can be useful to write JS code which runs in a browser and on Node.JS. I did it to write unit tests for a library a few years ago. That used [XMLHttpRequest from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) to make the object available to my code in Node.js.

However, once you start getting into the realm of DOM manipulation then it usually becomes more useful to test code in a browser environment such as is provided by [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).